# Small issue in a select query checking whether form data already exist in the database MySQL/ PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am creating a registration page, and before the data is inserted into my database I need to check to see whether it already exists, but the SQL request I'm generating is missing a ' at the end.

```
SELECT * from users where firstname = 'Bob' and lastname = 'Smith' and 
username = 'bobsmith' and email = 'bob@test.co.uk' and password = 'testing1
```

There is no ' showing after the password.

This is my PHP code:

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query1 = "SELECT * from users where firstname = '" .
    $firstname .
    "' and lastname = '" . 
    $lastname . 
    "' and username = '" .  
    $username .
    "' and email = '" . 
    $email . 
    "' and password = '" . $password;

echo "<BR>Running query ... <BR>" . $query1;
$result1 = mysqli_query($cxn,$query1);
$numrows1 = mysqli_affected_rows($cxn);
```

I have tried adding a quote to the end of password like `. $password . '";` however this is greying out the rest of the code below so it won't work. How can i fix this?

Update: I know this isn't the most secure way, but it is for a uni assignment and this is the way we are meant to do it.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: If you parameterize your queries you will not have this problem any more.

Comment: You're not adding a quote to the end of the password. It's not going to show up by magic. But I'm with Jay: parameterize, and you'll never have to worry about quoting issues again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of performing the query using MySQLi prepared statements:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$cxn= mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);

/* check connection */
if (!$cxn) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}

/* prepare the query */    
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($cxn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?"); // assuming username is unique
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);

/* execute prepared statement */
$result = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result(); 

/* get the user info */
$user = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

If you use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security you can then compare the stored password against `$password` using `password_verify($password, $user['stored_hash'])`. *Make sure you properly setup the database for hashed passwords.*

If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.